# Using jQuery each for multiple instance targeting and performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery plugins offer a method for multiple targeting by using class name instead of IDs.

For example (This is an example for Flexslider but it could be any jQuery plugin) :

```
$('.classname').flexslider();
```

However it's not a flexible method in some cases. In order to use different options for specific sliders, I use jQuery each() method :

```
$('.classname').each(function() { 
    $(this).flexslider();
});
```

Second option allows to use "data" attribute of the element and it's very helpful to override global slider values or modifying a specific instance.

Both method work perfectly but my question is using each() method in this case is OK or not? Because as far as I know, each() method waits up the show and the rest of the code will be triggered once each() loop is done. Does it affect performance?

---

**Edit :** Example configuration (original configuration is more complicated but I guess this one gives the idea) :

```
 $('.flexslider').each(function() { 

          tgallery = 0;

          if($(this).data('shortcode')=='gallery') {
                tgallery = 1;           
          }

          var animation = $(this).data('animation');

          $(this).fitVids().flexslider({
                animation : animation,
                pauseText: '<i class="fa fa-pause"></i>',
                playText: '<i class="fa fa-play"></i>', 
                prevText: '<i class="useicon"><</i>',
                nextText: '<i class="useicon">></i>', 
                start: function(slider){
                    if(tgallery) {
                        sliderAlign(slider); 
                    }       
                }
           });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you chain a jQuery method to a selector jQuery will perform an `each` loop internally anyway.

Thus creating your own `each` should have very very little performance impact. This impact should be imperceptible and not be a concern

The internal `each` loop will only have one element in the collection to loop over.

The pattern you are using is common when element specific data needs to be passed to plugin options

Comment: That's a relief. I've been thinking using multiple each() loop on the same js file may affect the performance but if triggering action work linear - same file or external file / function - that won't be an issue obviously. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1, because this logic can jQuery do for you. Don't repeat this.

You can simply use another classname or id for other configurations.

```
$('.otherClass').flexslider();
```

Alternative is using a combination of classnames in combination with the not selector:

```
$('.classname').not('.otherClass').flexslider();
```

So you can use the general .classname for general configuration and style. If you add another classname you can use a specific configuration.

```
<div class="classname otherClass"></div>
```

Comment: Using additional classes is helpful in some cases but it's not flexible enough when using custom functions through PHP or WP shortcodes. 

Could you elaborate why using foreach is not efficient?

Comment: Since this requires extra dom searches and since question relates to performance, this approach would likely be less performant than OP's solution

Comment: I edited the answer. To be honest, I'm supposed to use second option anyway but I wanted to know that if I should be looking for a better solution if it's huge impact on performance. Btw, thanks for your input @charlietfl

Comment: @Mertafor look inside source of the plugin ... should see something similar to `return this.each(...` . That is the internal loop my answer refers to

Comment: @charlietfl Absolutely. In fact there are more than one loop in the function. Obviously, logic is same and it's all good.